# How can I query MongoDB that gives me the maximum price of an object in a user-decided year in a java application?

Tags: java, mongodb

I' want to use following query:

```
db.listings_detail.aggregate([ {$match: {{$year: "$last_scraped"}: 2017}},  {$group: {_id: {max: {$max: "$price"}}}} ])
```

the schema is:

```
{
last_scraped: <String>
price: <int>
}
```

Last scraped is in spanish format dd/mm/yyyy and i don't know how to get only the year

On java i have this code:

```
AggregateIterable<Document> aggregate =
   collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.match(
   Filters.eq("last_scraped", 2017)), Aggregates.group("_id",
   cumulators.max("max", "$price"))));
```

the tests of the queries I do with MongoDB and then I have to implement it in Java

Comment: my idea was to use something similar to that Mongo query, I know it's not well written, but I don't know how to get the maximum price of only one year and not all the unsatisfied documents

Comment: What is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Please be as specific as possible when asking a question. Include your schema in your question description and explain why the query you have doesn't return the result you expect. If there's any error also include it. As already pointed out by @AMC refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve your question.

Comment: sorry, i have updated the question, I hope that the doubt is now better understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your schema is :

```
 {
    last_scraped: <String> //dd-mm-yyyy
    price: <int>
    }
```

You can do a find query with sort and select the first result

```
db.getCollection('listings_detail').find({"last_scraped": {"$regex": ".*2017$"} })
```

Although using mongo date data structure is recommened for date queries.
Ends with Regex is COLLSCAN, and will perform poorly as the data size grows.

Comment: Thank you, i have update de question, but is more o less what i was looking for, the only thing i need now y how to get the year of the string "last_scraped"

Comment: What is in the field last_scraped, can you provide an example ?

Comment: of course @Holy_diver, is the date where the object was last updated. For example 14/03/2017 in format dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: You can use regex, It will work good if data size is small. db.getCollection('listings_detail').find({"last_scraped": {"$regex": ".*2017$"} }) , But best practice is to use mongo data and then use $lte and $gte clauses to et data for an year. For this you need to change you db insert call first .